# What can single quote mean specially within double quotes?

Tags: bash, quoting

From bash manual

> Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) preserves the literal
>   value of all characters within the quotes, with the exception of ‘$’,
>   ‘‘’, ‘\’, and, when history expansion is enabled, ‘!’. The characters
>   ‘$’ and ‘‘’ retain their special meaning within double quotes (see
>   Section 3.5 [Shell Expansions], page 21).

What can single quote mean specially within double quotes?

The following example shows that single quotes within double quotes are treated literally not specially

```
$ echo "awk -F'[,/]' '{sub(/\/[0-9]*,/, "/" ($2+487) ",") }1' "
awk -F'[,/]' '{sub(/\/[0-9]*,/, / (+487) ,) }1'
```

Thanks.

Comment: What man page is that? Mine doesn't say anything about single quotes, nor does http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: @123  https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html#Quoting .. found from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: @spasic Those don't mention single quotes either (WRT double quoting and being special character).

Comment: @123 both the links I gave and `QUOTING` section in `man bash` say exceptions to be dollar, backtick and backslash.. I think OP mistook backtick as single quotes

Comment: Yep, they do, i also thought that, but in OP's post it is a single quote, not a backtick, which is why I was wondering what man page they got it from.

Comment: The passage you cite does not claim that a single quote inside double quote means anything. It claims the opposite: “Enclosing characters in double quotes (‘"’) **preserves the literal value** of [most characters including single quote]”. So why are you asking why the sky is red???

Comment: @Gilles  "with the **exception** of ‘$’, ‘‘’, ‘\’, ".

Comment: @Tim That exception list includes a *backquote*, not a *single quote*. The term *single quote* means the apostrophe and closing quote `'`, not the opening quote `\``.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's supposed to be a back-tick.  In the online manual for `bash` "4.3.39(1)-release" it says:

> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the literal value of
>          all  characters  within  the  quotes, with the exception of $, `, \,
>          and, when history expansion is enabled, !. The characters $  and  `
>          retain  their  special  meaning within double quotes.

What you're seeing is an issue with the typographical markup of the paragraph.

Comment: Thanks. Does backtick '`' here indicate command expansion?